# Apostrophe 's' at the end of an adjective?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, apostrophe

Hypothetically, I want to buy several things and they're all broken except for one of them which is too expensive.

Are any of the following sentences that describe this scenario, grammatically sound?

> The one-I-want-that's-not-broken's price is too high.
>
> The one I want that's not broken's price is too high.
>
> The one's-I-want-that's-not-broken price is too high.
>
> The one's I want that's not broken price is too high.

The bottom two sound absolutely terrible, and regarding the top two, I can't help feeling that it's wrong to attach an apostrophe 's' to the end of an adjective.

I'm not looking for better ways to phrase this.

Comment: I'd reword for better clarity: "The price of the unbroken one is too high." Don

Comment: @rhetorician: So would I. I know it's badly worded; that's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second alternative is grammatical, though it is hard to understand.  Adding brackets to indicate the structure:

> [The one I want that's not broken]'s price is too high.

A possessive can be formed by adding "'s" to a noun phrase, and here "the one I want that's not broken" is a noun phrase consisting of article "the" and noun "one" modified by two following relative clauses: "(that) I want" and "that's not broken".